# wget --page-requisites not downloading all images in data-srcset

Tags: web-scraping, wget

I am trying to scrape the images from a page which contains html similar to the following:

```
<img class="lazyload u-object-fit"
     data-srcset="/content/images/size/w400/img.jpeg 400w,
/content/images/size/w750/img.jpeg 750w,
/content/images/size/w960/img.jpeg 960w," data-sizes="auto"
       src="/content/images/size/w750/img.jpeg"
       srcset="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAEALAAAAAABAARAAAICTBEAOw=="
>
```

I am using the command `wget --page-requisites mydomain.com`.
It successfully downloads `/content/images/size/w750/img.jpeg` but not the other two images in `data-srcset`.
How can I use wget to download all the images?

Answer (score 0):

### With [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel):

```
xidel -e 'tokenize(//img/@data-srcset, "\s+\S+,") ! tokenize(.)' -s file.html |
    xargs -I{} echo wget https://domain.tld{}
```

### Output

Remove the `echo` command if the output looks good enough:

```
wget https://domain.tld/content/images/size/w400/img.jpeg
wget https://domain.tld/content/images/size/w750/img.jpeg
wget https://domain.tld/content/images/size/w960/img.jpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

To get those images you'll need to actually parse that website. This can be done with the HTML-parser [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel):

```
$ xidel -s "<url>" -e 'tokenize(//img/@data-srcset,"\s+\S+,\n?")[.]'
/content/images/size/w400/img.jpeg
/content/images/size/w750/img.jpeg
/content/images/size/w960/img.jpeg
```

Now just "follow" (with `-f`/`--follow`) these urls to get the content of these images.
Normally `--download .` would be enough, but since all 3 images are named *'img.jpeg'* you have to rename them:

```
$ xidel -s "<url>" \
  -f 'tokenize(//img/@data-srcset,"\s+\S+,\n?")[.]' \
  --download '{extract($url,"w\d+")}.jpeg'
```

This should download *'w400.jpeg'*, *'w750.jpeg'* and *'w960.jpeg'* in the current dir.